# Encode url and show in iframe

Tags: javascript, laravel, iframe, urlencode

I need to show some url in iframe at my own page... so I write:

```
Route::get('/preview/{url}', 'ArticlesController@preview');
```

my Controller function:

```
public function preview($url) {

        $url = urlencode($url);
            return view('pages.preview', compact('url'));


    }
```

and offcource my blade preview page (javascript):

```
function preview(){
    function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width = (newwidth) + "px";
};

    var content = '<iframe id="iframe2" src="{{$url}}" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none; position: relative;left: 0px;width: 100%; height:100%; top: 0;" name="myiFrame1" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%" onLoad="autoResize(iframe1);"></iframe>';

var newNode = document.createElement("DIV");  
newNode.innerHTML = content;
document.body.appendChild(newNode); 


};

preview();
```

Now when I try something like:

http://localhost:8888/preview/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dubaimajestic.com%2F

or

http://localhost:8888/preview/http://www.dubaimajestic.com

I get:

Not Found The requested resource /preview/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dubaimajestic.com%2F was not found on this server.

How to make this to WORK? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `http://www.dubaimajestic.com` has slashes in it, that doesn't work properly with the laravel router.

You can use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) to override this behaviour like this:

```
Route::get('preview/{url}', 'ArticlesController@preview')->where('url', '(.*)');
```

And this should work:

```
public function preview($url) {
    dd($url);
}
```

However I would switch to a different way because its a little cleaner in my opinion:

```
Route::get('preview', 'ArticlesController@preview');
```

Format your url like:

http://localhost:8888/preview?url=http://www.dubaimajestic.com

Which you can read like this in your controller:

```
public function preview(Request $request) {
    dd($request->input('url'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/` are making Laravel think that's part of path.

I would suggest making the URL a query string parameter like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/preview?url=http://www.dubaimajestic.com
```

And then in your `routes.php`:

```
// Don't accept {url} as an argument
Route::get('/preview', 'ArticlesController@preview');
```

And then in your controller:

```
public function preview() 
{
    $url = request()->url;

    return view('pages.preview', compact('url'));
}
```

That should work.